# Python tkinter widget resizes when it changes

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How can I prevent the widgets in this app from changing size when I press the toggle headings button?

I would like the two Treeviews to always take up 50% of the width of the window each

Currently the left one resizes when it gets more/less columns

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def toggle_headings():
    global htog
    if htog==0:
        t1.config(columns=columnswide)
        for i,h in enumerate(columnswide):
            c = ('#')+str(i)
            t1.heading(c,text=h)
        htog = 1
    else:
        t1.config(columns=columns)
        t1.heading(columns[0],text=columns[0])
        htog = 0
htog = 0

app = tk.Tk()

columnswide = ['abcd' for i in range(5)]
columns = ['abcd']
columnsbutton = tk.Button(app,text='toggle headings',command=toggle_headings)

t1 = ttk.Treeview(app,selectmode='browse',columns=columns)
t2 = ttk.Treeview(app,selectmode='browse',columns=columnswide)
for i,h in enumerate(columnswide):
    c = ('#')+str(i)
    t2.heading(c,text=h)
t1.heading(columns[0],text=columns[0])
for i in range(10):
    t1.insert('','end',text='testing '+str(i),values=['value'])
    t2.insert('','end',text='testing '+str(i),values=['value' for i in range(5)])

columnsbutton.pack(side='top',fill='x',expand=1)
t1.pack(side='left',fill='both',expand=1)
t2.pack(side='left',fill='both',expand=1)

app.mainloop()
```

In case anyone suggests using .grid(), I have tried this method below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def toggle_headings():
    global htog
    if htog==0:
        t1.config(columns=columnswide)
        for i,h in enumerate(columnswide):
            c = ('#')+str(i)
            t1.heading(c,text=h)
        htog = 1
    else:
        t1.config(columns=columns)
        t1.heading(columns[0],text=columns[0])
        htog = 0
htog = 0

app = tk.Tk()

columnswide = ['abcd' for i in range(5)]
columns = ['abcd']
columnsbutton = tk.Button(app,text='toggle headings',command=toggle_headings)

t1 = ttk.Treeview(app,selectmode='browse',columns=columns)
t2 = ttk.Treeview(app,selectmode='browse',columns=columnswide)
for i,h in enumerate(columnswide):
    c = ('#')+str(i)
    t2.heading(c,text=h)
t1.heading(columns[0],text=columns[0])
for i in range(10):
    t1.insert('','end',text='testing '+str(i),values=['value'])
    t2.insert('','end',text='testing '+str(i),values=['value' for i in range(5)])

columnsbutton.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
t1.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='nswe')
t2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='nswe')
app.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
app.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is a tough one, the Frame widget might help

Comment: @AlexBohm in the full version of the program both treeviews sit inside separate frame widgets and the effect of adding columns is the same, but thank you for the thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain @new_to_coding's solution in more detail:

Use `grid_columnconfigure()` for `Tkinter`.

As the first parameter of `grid_columnconfigure()` you need to set the column index.

Note that there are additional parameters. For example, some column can grow more than other when resized.

- `minsize`: Defines the minimum size for the column. Note that if a column is completely empty, it will not be displayed, even if this option is set.
- `pad`: Padding to add to the size of the largest widget in the column when setting the size of the whole column.
- `weight`: A relative weight used to distribute additional space between columns. A column with the weight 2 will grow twice as fast as a column with weight 1. The default is 0, which means that the column will not grow at all.
- `uniform`: When a non-empty value is supplied, places the column in a `uniform group` with other columns that have the same value for `uniform`. The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their `weight` values.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with this option:

```
app.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1,uniform='x')
app.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1,uniform='x')
```

it makes each column proportional size

Comment: There goes your bounty :)